# A question about ChoiceDialog

Tags: dialog-window

Consider some test list that I call `LongList`:

```
LongList = Table["Some very-very long name", 300];
```

I would like to use `ChoiceDialog` to associate some `parameter` with an element of the list.

```
parameter = 
 ChoiceDialog["Choose the experiment:", LongList, 
  Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 1}]
```

This does not work properly: the dialog window has fixed height, and it is impossible to scroll, so the list does not fit the window:
[image]

If changing `Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 1}` to `Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 10}`, I do not fix the problem but gain an additional one instead, coming from the fact that the width of the window stays the same. As a result, 1) only 4 buttons match the window, and 2) the buttons cannot be wide enough to fit the list elements properly:
[image]

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChoiceDialog.html) on `ChoiceDialog` is very poor and does not include any description about changing its design.

Could you please tell me how to fix this problem (either allow scrolling down or scrolling left-right, with wide enough buttons)?

Comment: Do you insist on using `ChoiceDialog`? What about using a dropdown menu with [`PopupMenu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html)?

Comment: @Domen : `ChoiceDialog` is the only option I know how to use, at least for some special examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From UX perspective, I strongly suggest using a drop-down menu with [`PopupMenu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html) instead. The code below works the same as `ChoiceDialog`: It opens a pop-up dialog, then returns the selected value.

```
dropdownDialog[list_] := 
 DialogInput[{choice = ""}, 
  Column[{PopupMenu[Dynamic[choice], list], 
    Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]

dropdownDialog[LongList]
```

[image]

If you insist on buttons, you can use `DialogNotebook` with `"VerticalScrollBar"`.

```
buttonsDialog[list_] := 
  DialogInput[
   DialogNotebook[
    Grid[Partition[
      Table[With[{opt = opt}, 
        Button[opt, DialogReturn[opt], ImageSize -> Automatic]], {opt,
         LongList}], 4]]], WindowElements -> {"VerticalScrollBar"}, 
   WindowSize -> Medium];

buttonsDialog[LongList]
```

[image]