# How to select only particular values from the list using dialog windows?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dialog-window

Consider some list:

```
list = {"A","B","C","D"}
```

How to select only particular values from it using a dynamic dialog window that prevents the code below it from evaluating before the choice is made (by using e.g. [`DialogInput`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283594/a-question-about-choicedialog))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html).

```
selectionDialog[list_] := 
 DialogInput[{choice = {}}, 
  Column[{TogglerBar[Dynamic[choice], list], 
    Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]

list = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
selectionDialog[list]
```